# MongoDB sort by the sum of specified object inside inner array

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have some documents like:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1, 
    "inner_array" : [
        {
            "object_value" : 1, 
        }, 
        {
            "object_value" : 2, 
        }, 
        {
            "object_value" : 1, 
        }, 
    ]
}

{ 
    "_id" : 2, 
    "inner_array" : [
        {
            "object_value" : 1, 
        }, 
        {
            "object_value" : 1, 
        }, 
        {
            "object_value" : 1, 
        }, 
    ]
}
```

In the first document there are two objects inside the "inner_array" with an "object_value" 1. Now I want to sort the documents by the total number of objects  inside "inner_array" whose "object_value" is 1. So as the example above, the sort key of the first document is 2 and the second one is 3.

I do some searches but still can't figure out a way rather than get all the documents and write code to filter and sort. How can I do this in native mongo instruction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MongoDB's [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) framework to get the query results that you specified.

The aggregation framework allows you to break down your processing into one or more stages where each stage does some basic work such as filtering, grouping, transforming the results at that particular stage. The [aggregation stage operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#stage-operators) support this processing.

---

As a result, one way to approach your query is by using aggregation and establishing the following stages:

1. [Unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) your `inner_array` array. This will facilitate being able to count the `inner_array.object_value` that equal `1`.
2. [Group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) your results so that we get a total count of how `inner_array.object = 1` per document.

   In the `totalCount` calculation, the `$sum` occurs only for `inner_array.object_value` elements that have a value of `1`.

   Also in the grouping, I add `inner_array` back to the stage results since I am assuming that you want to see all the document elements in your final result set.
3. [Sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) the stage results by `totalCount` in ascending order (use `-1` for descending order).
4. [Project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) the results to eliminate the `totalCount` field from your final results.

---

If your collection is called `yourcollection` then this is what your aggregation query would look like as described in the steps above.

```
db.yourcollection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind" : "$inner_array" },
    { "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$_id",
        "totalCount" : { 
            "$sum" : { 
                "$cond" : {
                    "if" : { "$eq" : [ "$inner_array.object_value", 1 ] },
                    "then" : 1,
                    "else" : 0
                 }
            }
        },
        "inner_array" : {
            "$push" : {
                "object_value" : "$inner_array.object_value"
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$sort" : { "totalCount" : 1 } },
    { "$project" : {
          "inner_array" : 1
    }}
])
```

---

I suggest that you run the query starting with the first stage only (`$unwind`) so that you can see what each stage produces. Add the next stage to see how it changes your results and then the next and so forth.

Finally, this query does not consider performance as it is not in the immediate scope of this question. Just know that if you have a large data set then you could take advantage of indexes and modify your aggregation query to use those indexes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and great suggestion! After I construct the `$unwind` stage, I can see what I have and construct other stages on my own. So finally I get this:
`db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {$unwind:'$inner_array'},
    {$match:{'inner_array.object_value':1}},
    {$group: {_id:'$_id', totalCount:{$sum:1}}},
    {$sort: {totalCount:1}}
])`

Comment: @KevinXi I'm glad my suggestion helped. Your updated aggregate query is perfect.